# Flask Application - view posts of current user only

Tags: python, python-requests, flask-sqlalchemy

Beginner programmer here. Trying to create a flask app which users can post into. I am looking to create a "home page" where users can see their posts rather than every users posts.

Here is my code:

routes.py

```
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    posts = Post.query.all()
    return render_template('home.hmtl', posts=posts)
```

models.py

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
  email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
  image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
  password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
  posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

  def __repr__(self):
     return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"


class Post(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
  date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
  content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
  user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

  def __repr__(self):
     return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should be able to do something like `posts = current_user.posts` as long as you know the `current_user`

Answer (score 1):

First of all get, get the current user using **session** or **jwt's**.
Then you can now query your database to get posts by the current user only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use current_user case

```
@app.route("/home",  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
posts = current_user.posts
return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)
```